# How to Close a Window in the OnWindowRendred event handler?

Tags: c#, wpf

`OnContentRendred` will initiate License checking, if there's no valid license I'll provide a `LicenseWindow` to select one. If the user closes the LicenseWindow without selecting a valid license, the `MainWindow` will be closed too.

**This is the Handler of the `OnContentRendred`- Event of `MainWindow`:**

```
    private void CheckLicenseOnContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ContentRendered -= CheckLicenseOnContentRendered;
        try
        {
            Initialize(); // may throw LicenseException
        }
        catch (LicenseException)
        {
            var licenseWindow = new LicenseWindow();
            if (licenseWindow.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                // Do Stuff if valid License selected
            }
            else
            {
                this.Close(); // <-- NullReferenceException
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Other Exceptions will be handled here
        }

    }
```

As tagged in the codesample the `this.Close()` results in a `NullReferenceException`.

> I did some debugging and with the ImmediateWindow I managed to find out that `this` is not null (as it should be)

**So then why could `this.Close()` cause a `NullReferenceException` and maybe how do I Close the Window in an other way?**

EDIT:
**Stack Trace:**

```
   bei Giag.DataReader.ControlLibrary.Windows.MainWindow.WindowClosing(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\...\Windows\MainWindow.xaml.cs:Zeile 210.
   bei System.Windows.Window.OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
   bei System.Windows.Window.WmClose()
   bei System.Windows.Window.WindowFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   bei System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.PublicHooksFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
  bei MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   bei MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
  bei System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
  bei MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
  bei System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
  bei MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
  bei MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.UnsafeSendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
  bei System.Windows.Window.InternalClose(Boolean shutdown, Boolean ignoreCancel)
  bei System.Windows.Window.Close()
  bei Giag.DataReader.ControlLibrary.Windows.MainWindow.CheckLicenseOnContentRendered(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\...\Windows\MainWindow.xaml.cs:Zeile 236.
   bei System.Windows.Window.OnContentRendered(EventArgs e)
   bei System.Windows.Window.<PostContentRendered>b__4(Object unused)
   bei System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   bei MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   bei System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   bei System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   bei System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   bei System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   bei System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   bei MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   bei MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   bei System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   bei MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   bei System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   bei MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   bei MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   bei System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   bei System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   bei System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   bei System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   bei System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   bei System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   bei System.Windows.Application.Run()
   bei FrameworkTestClient.App.Main() in d:\...\FrameworkTestClient\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:Zeile 0.
   bei System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   bei System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   bei System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   bei System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

EDIT 2:

In a test Project the code above works fine.. So I will need to find the Fault somewhere else. Thanks for your help, i'll keep you in touch.

Comment: Can you try wiring up the OnClosed handler for the LicenseWindow and closing the main window inside that handler , if needed. I suspect that the LicenseWindow does not close before you initiate the close for the main window..

Comment: It is better to put the checking before the main window being initialized. Somewhere in the `OnStartup` method in App.xaml.cs. Do you have a particular reason that you need to do this in `OnWindowRendered`?

Comment: @kennyzx Yes, it's a Class Library and it's internal Settings Management can only be reached when already several instances have been created.

Comment: @bit that might be a possibility but it sounds a bit complicated to me, because the `ShowDialog()` does this already when the LicenseWindow is Closing.

Comment: @LuckyLikey can't you cast `sender` to typeof `MainWindow` and close it then ?

Comment: @tchrikch `((MainWindow)sender).Close();` does also cause a `NullReferenceException`. in this case it's the the `sender` refers to the same object as `this`.

Comment: @LuckyLikey I tried to reproduce this (simple wpf app that on `ContentRendered` throws exception and refers to `this` keyword ) and there is no `NullReferenceException`. Can you post stack trace of the exception ? Or is there anything unusual in the window structure ?

Comment: @tchrikch No everything normal.. stacktrace posted is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an Error in the `Closing` Event handler.

One will learn debugging correctly sometime...
Thanks to all to you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but if you want to exit the whole program if no license is found, you can use `Application.Current.Shutdown();` to close the main window and exit application.

Comment: You understood correctly, but `Application.Current.Shutdown();` does also cause a `NullReferenceException`